# Generate Duplicate (n) files in a folder in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create/generate multiple (n) copies(cloning) of a file with sequential number assigned to the filename.

***nodejs code snippet***

```
const fs = require('fs');
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

fs.copyFile(
      './1.jpeg',
      './'+i+'.jpeg',
      err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error Occurred:', err);
        } else {
          console.log('File Copied Successfully!');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try to run the above program

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
```

Can someone please help me getting this fixed? How do we achieve this?

Comment: which node version are you using?

Comment: Your code runs on Node 17.

Answer (score 0):

The `fs.copyFile` function is used as follows (from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-copyfile-function/)):

```
fs.copyFile( src, dest, mode, callback )
```

In your code, the callback you provided is interpreted as mode, and so callback is null. The mode should be one of `fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL`, `fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE`, and `fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE_FORCE`.